# A page for questions sorted based on last significant modification (not tag-edits)

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, views

I think it should be possible to see questions sorted based on the time that the last significant activity is performed on them. And in place of stating who has performed last activity on the question, it should say who has performed the last significant activity on them. It will be page similar to the new questions page.

The main example of **insignificant / uninteresting activity** is tag edits (which don't add any information to a question/answers, they are mainly an organizational modification which is not an interesting activity for most users), but small edits to questions/answers (like spelling corrections) might also be considered insignificant and uninteresting.

Note that users who want to check tag-edits and insignificant modification can still see them, this feature will only allow users who don't want to see those uninteresting modification the possibility of avoiding them. Also the OP is always notified when their question is edited.

---

related:

[Please prevent adding/removing/changing tags from bumping them to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/please-prevent-adding-removing-changing-tags-from-bumping-them-to-the-front-page)

[Front page flood rate control system for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/system-to-minimize-the-soft-problems-due-to-manual-retagging)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Comment: In particular, please stop flooding RSS with minor updates as defined by Kaveh.