# Button for mods to not bump a question on a retag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I really, really want to do a mass cleanup of the [vmware](/questions/tagged/vmware) on Server Fault. There are > 100 questions that need to be re-tagged, and there's no one-size-fits-all merge that I can do.

I realise there is a feature request to stop flooding the front page with retags (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/system-to-minimize-the-soft-problems-due-to-manual-retagging) for similar, but not the same, requests), but all that's in place is a traffic flow so they don't all bump at the same time.

What I propose is for >10k (or 15k or 20k) users and diamond mods to have a "Do not bump" option when re-tagging.

[image: Save and don't bump]

This way I can re-tag to my hearts delight, safe in the knowledge that I haven't bumped all the new questions off the front page.

Comment: Those linked certainly sound exactly the same

Comment: @Random - one of them is asking for a queue so that they get bumped over a period of time, not all at once (I propose they don't get bumped at all). The other one started out asking for not to bump, but ended up being about mass retagging.

Comment: They should still appear somewhere in the modtools so other high rep users can review the changes.

Answer (score 2):

How about a check box labelled [ ] **bump**, visible only to users > 5K or perhaps users > 10K.  I don't have this much reputation and I would appreciate this feature too, but I understand the desire to auto-bump lower rep user edits/retags to make these more visible and facilitate review.