# Detagging 'featured' should not bump

Tags: feature-request, bump, featured-tag

When the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is removed from a question, the question is [bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578), as with any other edit. I propose that, when that is the only change to a question, it not be bumped: the point of detagging is to call attention *away* from the question, and bumping the question defeats that purpose.

Note that there's an outstanding feature request for [retagging not to bump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29394) (and [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241)), and one for [mod edits optionally not to bump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96964), but this is more specific than either of those, and where public policy may dictate those be denied, this may be worth granting anyway.

Comment: I agree that it is somewhat counter-intuitive, but really, how often is the [meta-tag:featured] tag *really* used? I think this is too much of a corner case to truly be worth the effort needed to implement it.

Answer (score 7):

This strikes me as a peculiar request, since the functionality *already exists:* after 30 days, the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is automatically removed from the question by the system, without actually generating a new revision and thus without bumping.

Remember also that the tag is moderator-only and serves to pin the question in the Community Bulletin board - something that can also be accomplished by creating an *event* (which doesn't bump anything) or simply relying on the default "hotness" logic (which, needless to say, also doesn't bump anything and additionally limits itself to questions posted [within the past two weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-is-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined/130893#130893)).

What I'm getting at is this: you never actually have to use [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) in the first place, and when you *do* use it you don't have to manually remove it - but if you do find yourself needing such fine-grained control over how and when certain meta posts are promoted, you should probably just be using events.

Comment: Good points. +1.